# Evaluating database() in a query

Tags: mysql, database, function, evaluate

How can I use database() within a query? Here's an example what I'm trying to do:

```
select database();
```

Returns "my_table"

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS where 
table_schema = database() and 
table_name = 'my_table' AND index_name = 'my_index' LIMIT 1;
```

Doesn't work

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS where 
table_schema = (select database()) and 
table_name = 'my_table' AND index_name = 'my_index' LIMIT 1;
```

Doesn't work

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS where 
table_schema = 'my_table' and 
table_name = 'my_table' AND index_name = 'my_index' LIMIT 1;
```

Works like a charm

So the question is, how can I evaluate the database() within the query to make the query dynamic? I need a query to check if a certain index already exists so the scripts knows if it needs to add it or not.

Comment: All of these queries work fine on my machine. I'm on mysql 5.5.30-MariaDB on Ubuntu.

Comment: `where table_schema = 'my_table'` Is your *database* named "my_table"?

Comment: They don't seem to work on MySQL. Any ideas?